# Excel - Select Case with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is sort of an excerpt of my full Sub just because it'll be easier to read here. I need to add more criteria to some of the cases, and I'm not sure how to implement that.

To sum up what this is doing, in a row, if column K has a word that begins with B, M, or D, it runs a set of cases. If column K has a word that begins with an A, it runs a different set of cases. Again, this is working. But in some of these cases, I need it to have more criteria instead of only looking at column O.

For example, in the first case, it needs to check for "University of Illinois" and "UofI," but it also needs to check column P for the values of "Urbana" and "Chicago." How can I do that?

```
Sub Test4()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastRow = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 84 To LastRow
        If Range("K" & i) Like "B*" Or Range("K" & i) Like "M*" Or Range("K" & i) Like "D*" Then
            Select Case Range("O" & i)
                Case "University of Illinois", "UofI"
                    Range("N" & i) = "1234"
            End Select
        End If
        If Range("K" & i) Like "A*" Then
            Select Case Range("O" & i)
                Case "New York University", "NYU"
                    Range("N" & i) = "5075"
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You could perhaps turn your select case statements round to `Select Case True` and then your first case could be `Range("O" & i)= "University of Illinois" and Range("P" & i)="Urbana"` (but then arguably you might as well use `If`).

Comment: If the conditions for the various cases involve multiple criteria based on multiple values, why not just use an `If - Then - ElseIf ...` cascade rather than `Select Case`? That allows you to use Boolean operators in the conditions.

Comment: @Robby try the code in my work-around answer below, there is a way to "Cheat" the `Select Case` to work with the `Like` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Case Range("O" & i)
    Case "University of Illinois", "UofI"
        Select Case Range("P" & i")
            Case "Urbana", "Chicago"
                Range("N" & i) = "1234"
        End Select
End Select
```

Does this suffice? Have not tested so please feedback so we can get you to a solution

Comment: That's close. "Urbana" and "Chicago" need to be different cases. That points me in the right direction though. If I separate them into separate cases, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Under normal circumstances, the `Select Case` statement doesn't work with the `Like` operator. However, there is a work-around.

In order for the `Select Case` to work with the `Like`, we will add a `True` expression.

**Code**

```
Sub Test4()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastRow = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 84 To LastRow

        Dim wordStr
        wordStr = Range("K" & i)

        ' adding True to enter the below Case with Like
        Select Case True
            Case wordStr Like "B*", wordStr Like "M*", wordStr Like "D*"
                Select Case Range("O" & i)
                    Case "University of Illinois", "UofI"
                        Range("N" & i) = "1234"

                End Select

            Case wordStr Like "A*"
                Select Case Range("O" & i)
                    Case "New York University", "NYU"
                        Range("N" & i) = "5075"

                End Select

        End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That is a neat trick, although I feel ambivalent about it in terms of readability.

Answer (score 0):

since you need to catch *"word that begins with"* you could go like this

```
Sub Test4()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    LastRow = Range("O" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 84 To LastRow
        Select Case Left(Range("K" & i).Value, 1)
            Case "B", "M", "D"
                Select Case Range("O" & i).Value
                    Case "University of Illinois", "UofI"
                        Range("N" & i) = "1234"
                End Select
            Case "A"
                Select Case Range("O" & i).Value
                    Case "New York University", "NYU"
                        Range("N" & i) = "5075"
                End Select
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```